# Python: replace two or more spaces followed by a specified character with a single space followed by that character

Tags: python

How do I replace two or more spaces followed by a specified character with a single space followed by that character, so that for example `"   &"` become `" &"`. I could successively run

```
str = str.replace("  &"," &")
```

but that is slow.

Comment: So you're looking to just replace double space `  ` with ` ` ? or just when it precedes any character like `@#!` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Use reflex

```py
import re
pattern = re.compile(r' +&')
string = '  &      &    h'
print(pattern.sub(' &', string))
```

Output

```
 & &    h
```

Answer (score 0):

replace one or more spaces with a single space:

```
import re
# match 1 or more spaces and then any non space character
pattern = re.compile(r'(\s+)([^\s]+)')
# replace with single space and keep second group
res = pattern.sub(r' \2', string)
```